# Delete an HTML element containing a pattern

Tags: html, regex, sed

How can I delete elements (from `<span>` to `</span>`) whose text contain `PATTERN` in it? The contents of the element should be deleted along with the element.

For example, I want to delete the first `<span>...</span>` element in the following:

```
<span><SPAN>some text with
with </SPAN> a PATTERNin it etc</span><span><SPAN>some text
without </SPAN> a thingIn it etc</span>
```

to produce, using SED only :

```
<span><SPAN>some text
without </SPAN> a thingIn it etc</span>
```

PS: No help with end of lines or solo words, it must just detect any `<span>...</span>` and `PATTERN`.

Production server only allow basic commands such as SED.
I'm currently using the following but it's ugly and doesn't seem to work.

```
sed '/<span.*\n.*PATTERN.*<\/span>/d'
```

Comment: What's a "balise"? And what should the desired output look like?

Comment: your description is unclear. What do you mean with all that?

Comment: What did you try? Show your effort and make a [mcve].

Comment: Added clarity, result & progress

Comment: Is it HTML or XHTML?

Comment: it is HTML but not sure it would pass the WW3 agreement. It's result of 3 barbaric scripts i don't have hands on.

Comment: Pity. Might have tried writing a sed-based parser for fun if it was XHTML (to show how silly it is), but HTML is far far more complicated, and you say you don't even have HTML? How do you expect us to parse it, then??

Answer (score 0):

If HTML:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
   my $doc = $parser->parse_html_file($ARGV[0]);
   $_->unbindNode()
      for $doc->findnodes(q{//span[contains(text(), "PATTERN")]});

   binmode(STDOUT);
   print($doc->toString());
' in.html >out.html
```

If XHTML:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
   my $doc = $parser->parse_file($ARGV[0]);
   my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
   $xpc->registerNs( h => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" );
   $_->unbindNode()
      for $xpc->findnodes(q{//h:span[contains(text(), "PATTERN")]}, $doc);

   binmode(STDOUT);
   print($doc->toString());
' in.xhtml >out.xhtml
```

The above both produce the following (with some implied elements vivified):

```
<span><SPAN>some text
without </SPAN> a thingIn it etc</span>
```

Comment: I see your point (good one), but i'm on a server where i can't use perl but only standard bash commands...

Comment: 1) I thought you wanted to use `sed`, not `bash`? 2) I'm not writing an HTML parser in `bash` (that would be silly) or `sed` (probably not even possible).

Comment: sed is in my allowed range of commands. Sadly i can't chose everything for production servers...